# SQL Server: find and remove dups in a table

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I am not familiar with SQL programming, I understand there were posts about removing dups before but this is a little more complicated and I haven't found a solution online.

The requirement: I have a table `Positions` with columns `A`, `B`, `C`, `total`, `date`.

- Two rows are regarded as dups only when the values of `A, B, C` all match.
- once dups are found, choose the row whose `date` is *not* empty and update the value of `total` of that row by summing up the `total` of all dups rows;
- remove the other dups except for the row chosen in the above step.

The chosen SQL is SQL Server.

please help. John

Comment: This logic is easy enough to implement after the fact.  Just insert the rows and take the sum.  Otherwise, you'll need a trigger.

Comment: w.r.t *once dups are found, choose the row whose date is not empty and update the value of "total" of that row by summing up the "total" of all dups rows;*, should the total to be updated include the total of the row with date?

Comment: Then what you have tried so far ? , atleast try something.

Comment: dups means duplicates? Sorry cause I'm bad Eng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can try as follows to update the table.

```
update POSITIONS as a
set total = (select sum(total) from positions as b 
where a.col1 = b.col1 
and a.col2 = b.col2 
and a.col3 = b.col3)
WHERE a.date is not null
```

If you don't want the total of row with date to be included in the sum, then you have to tweek the query accordingly.

The following ***assumptions*** were made as your question is not very clear.

1) There will be only one row with non empty date
2) No need to update if all the dates available are empty

Next time, try to include as much info as possible with your question for us to guide better.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

First, you calculate `SUM` total value `Group by A,B,C` `Where date not null`.

Then, you `update total = SUM (calculated step one)`.

Last, you `select DISTINCT A,B,C,total`

Try this code:

```
UPDATE POSITIONS AS P
SET total = (SELECT SUM(total)
             FROM POSITIONS
             WHERE A = P.A
               AND B = P.B
               AND C = P.C)
WHERE date IS NOT NULL

SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C,total
FROM POSITIONS
WHERE date IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE_Position
AS
(
SELECT 'Test' AS A, 1 AS B, 1 AS C, 5 AS Total, CONVERT(DATE, '05/10/2018') AS [Date]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Test' AS A, 1 AS B, 2 AS C, 6 AS Total, NULL AS [Date]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Test' AS A, 2 AS B, 3 AS C, 5 AS Total, CONVERT(DATE, '05/10/2018') AS [Date]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Test' AS A, 2 AS B, 4 AS C, 6 AS Total, NULL AS [Date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Test' AS A, 3 AS B, 5 AS C, 5 AS Total, CONVERT(DATE, '05/10/2018') AS [Date]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Test' AS A, 3 AS B, 6 AS C, 6 AS Total, NULL AS [Date]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Test' AS A, 4 AS B, 7 AS C, 5 AS Total, CONVERT(DATE, '05/10/2018') AS [Date]
)
SELECT p1.A, p1.B, p1.C
,Total = (CASE WHEN SUM(p2.Total) IS NULL OR SUM(p2.Total) = 0 THEN SUM(p1.Total)
ELSE SUM(p1.Total + p2.Total) END)
,p1.[Date]
FROM CTE_Position p1
LEFT JOIN CTE_Position p2
ON p1.A = p2.A
AND p1.B = p2.B 
AND p2.[Date] IS NULL
WHERE
p1.[Date] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
p1.A, p1.B, p1.C, p1.[DATE]
```